# Windows 10 Title Bar blocking menus

Tags: windows

[image: Blender 2.80 beta]Both on 2.79b and 2.80 beta, I am unable to see the top menu line.  It is being blocked by the windows title bar.  I'm running on a laptop with a built in Intel 620 graphics.  I assume that is the problem.  Is there any workaround?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you edit you post and add an image?

Comment: Maybe going full screen (Alt+F11) could fix the problem ? Anyway, you should submit a bug report.

Comment: Added image of 2.80 beta.  In 2.79 (Alt+F11) takes care of the issue.  Have never submitted a bug report but will give it a try...

Comment: Submitted bug:   T61057: Windows 10 Title Bar blocking menus.  Thanks to all for commenting.